# Setting pixel value from 0 to 10

Tags: qgis, pixel

How can I change the pixel value from 0 to 10 on QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Use raster calculator.

Comment: If you would like to change all zeros to ten in your raster then you can use raster calculator. To change a single pixel value you need gimp or similar image manipulation program.

Comment: I would like to change all 0 values to 10. How can I write this into the Raster Calculator? Thank you very much

Comment: Please try `("YourRaster@1" = 0) * 10 + ("YourRaster@1" != 0) * ("YourRaster@1")`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it workd. Let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allow me to rephrase the question "change the pixel value from 0 to 10" as follows;

- if the pixel value equals 0, then change it to 10.
- if the pixel value is not 0, then keep the original pixel value.

(1) The first one is expressed as `("YourRaster@1" = 0) * 10`.

- (A) when the pixel value is `0`, condition `("YourRaster@1" = 0)` returns `True` which is `1`. Then `1 * 10` becomes `10`.
- (B) when the pixel value is not 0, condition `("YourRaster@1" = 0)` returns `False` which is `0`. Then `0 * 10` becomes `0`.

(2) The second one is expressed as `("YourRaster@1" != 0) * ("YourRaster@1")`.

- (C) when the pixel value is `0`, condition `("YourRaster@1" != 0)` returns `False`. Then `0 * ("YourRaster@1")` becomes `0`.
- (D) when the pixel value is not `0`, condition `("YourRaster@1" != 0)` returns `True`. Then `1 * ("YourRaster@1")` becomes `("YourRaster@1")` (i.e. your original pixel value).

(3) Finally, by putting these two together, `("YourRaster@1" = 0) * 10 + ("YourRaster@1" != 0) * ("YourRaster@1")` will work this way:

- When the pixel value is `0`, (A) + (C) becomes `10 + 0`, which is `10`.
- When the pixel value is not `0`, (B) + (D) becomes `0 + "YourRaster@1"`, which is the pixel value of your original raster.